# text to xls file creation

Tags: shell-script, csv, spreadsheet

I have 4 text files in my unix system want to put data into a xls file and send it via mail.

text1.txt:

```
100
150
130
120
110
```

text2.txt:

```
200
230
240
250
260
..
..
..
```

so on ...

I want to have `text1.txt` file data in first column, `text2.txt` file data in second column and finally on the end want the summation of data in each row.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/741099/run-shell-script-to-take-output-of-a-file-and-convert-it-into-excel-format

Comment: You don't mention what you want done with the other two files.  Also, given that most spreadsheets can import CSV files, is CSV sufficient or do you really need a `.xls` file?   CSV is easy, .xls is much harder and requires using a language like perl or python which have libraries for reading and writing .xls files.

Comment: @cas, to send it by mail he'll have to print it out anyway so `csv` or `tsv` should be fine....  :D

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: join the files in a multicolumn file:

```
paste f1 f2 f3 > _1.tsv
```

Step 2: add a formula to calculate the sum:

```
gawk '1;END{for(i=0;i<NF;i++)
              {printf("=SUM(%c1:%c%d)\t",65+i,65+i,NR)} print ""}' _1.tsv > _2.tsv
```

Step 3: inspect the result

```
$ cat _2.tsv
   100 100 100
   ...
   99  99  99
   =SUM(A1:A5) =SUM(B1:B5) =SUM(C1:C5)

$ gnumeric _2.tsv             # excel, whatever your favorite spreadsheet
```

Step 4: (probably not necessary) if you really want a `.xls` file:

```
ssconvert _2.tsv  _2.xls
```

`ssconvert` comes with `gnumeric` fantastic spreadsheet (`apt-get install gnumeric` if necessary); Several conversions formats available.

```
ssconvert _2.tsv  _2.pdf
ssconvert _2.tsv  _2.txt
```

As expected, these txt and pdf files have formulas replaced by their results.

### Update:

to have a column with the line sum, Step 2 could be:

```
gawk '{printf("%s\t=SUM(A%d,%c%d)\n", $0, NR, NF+64, NR)}' < _1.tsv
 100    1   90  =SUM(A1,C1)
 241    2   23  =SUM(A2,C2)
 312    3   3   =SUM(A3,C3)
```

where:

- `NR` stands for the number of the line (Number of Register) and
- `NF` Number of Fields

Comment: what will `ssconvert` do ? _2.tsv already have tabs and can be imported in excel.

Comment: @Archemar, good questions, tsv is find for me, but the PO was asking for a `xls`... ( I will add anote about it)

Comment: Thanks for your replies ... But i want the sum of data in each row not in each column. Sorry but i am not that much familiar with NF and NR.

Now i am getting output like 

100 100 100
   ...
   99  99  99
   =SUM(A1:A5) =SUM(B1:B5) =SUM(C1:C5)

But i want something like below

100  100  100  300
....
99   99    99    297

please help me with the loop . Thanks a lot in advance.